# Android Load Large Image For Printing

Tags: android, printing, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm working on an design app. It needs to create a very large invisible view with image inside then convert it into bitmap for printing purpose, but Android doesn't let me load a such huge image into memory. Is there any solutions to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to take invisible view and load image in that. You can directly load the image in your image view and convert it into bitmap, Here is my code where I have loaded image in XML and then converted whole XML file in bitmap because I have many other things which I want to convert in Bitmap.I hope this code will help you.

`RawMapInfoWindowBinding rawMapInfoWindowBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.raw_map_info_window, (ConstraintLayout) mBinding.getRoot(), false);`

`rawMapInfoWindowBinding.clLike.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            rawMapInfoWindowBinding.clLike.layout(0, 0, rawMapInfoWindowBinding.clLike.getMeasuredWidth(), rawMapInfoWindowBinding.clLike.getMeasuredHeight());`

I used glide to load my Image

```
enter code here

    try {

        GlideApp.with(this).asBitmap().centerCrop().circleCrop().load(statusModel.profileurl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "onLoadFailed: " + statusModel.statusID);
                Log.e(TAG, "onLoadFailed --------- " + isSearching);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
           rawMapInfoWindowBinding.ivProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           return true;
            }
        }).submit(100, 100);

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Comment: the problem is printing need high quality image but I can't load a huge image with size up 20Mb into memory

Comment: why do you need to convert image in bitmap?

Comment: Because I need to let users take some modification